# Infinite Loop on Android when attempting to create credentials for Watson's Speech To Text. while (!credentials.HasIamTokenData())

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, amazon-iam, ibm-watson

I created a simple app to test IBM Watson's Speech To Text. My plan is to deploy an Android app using it. My app works when playing on Unity, but does not work after building and running on my Android device.

Through exploring Logcat on Android Studio, I found that it was hitting an infinite loop in the while loop mentioned in the title. My credentials part of my code is below as well.

Again, it works on my PC. Does not work after building and deploying on Android. Does anyone know what I'm missing? I'm assuming it's something specific to do with Android but I'm not sure. I've hit a dead end googling for answers.

```
private void Start()
 {
     Debug.Log("Start");
     recordedText = GameObject.Find("RecordedText").GetComponent<Text>();
     LogSystem.InstallDefaultReactors();
     // create Watson service
     Runnable.Run(CreateService());
     // note if there are mic devices found
     foreach (string device in Microphone.devices)
     {
         Debug.Log(device);
     }

     audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
 }

 // creates Watson credentials and initializes STT service
 private IEnumerator CreateService()
 {

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_iamApikey))
     {
         throw new WatsonException("Plesae provide IAM ApiKey for the service.");
     }

     //  Create credential and instantiate service
     Credentials credentials = null;

     //  Authenticate using iamApikey
     TokenOptions tokenOptions = new TokenOptions()
     {
         IamApiKey = _iamApikey
     };

     credentials = new Credentials(tokenOptions, _serviceUrl);

     if(credentials != null) Debug.Log("Credentials is not null!");
     //  Wait for tokendata
     while (!credentials.HasIamTokenData())
     {
         Debug.Log("In the while loop"); // INFINITE LOOP ON ANDROID
         yield return null;
     }

     Debug.Log("OUT of the while loop");

     _speechToText = new SpeechToText(credentials); // NEVER REACHES ON ANDROID
 }
```

Comment: It seems like an error has occurred, but you didn't catch it. Have you implemented the fail check?  `private void OnFail(RESTConnector.Error error, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    Log.Debug("OnFail()", "Failed: {0}", error.ToString());
}`

Comment: Can you see if you ever get to `OnRequestIamTokenResponse` in Credentials.cs? Or if you get a response code in RESTConnector.cs in [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/1b264e1c9548ef53d4df153c7351ceb0d74b2a41/Scripts/Connection/RESTConnector.cs#L608) line?

Comment: I put in some Log.Critical messages in both places you specified, taj, and Android Studio did not show anything. I also do have OnFail implemented but that isn't called until I try to call the api. But since the SpeechToText service isn't even made (after the while loop), I will get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I am guessing that the loop is in `while (!credentials.HasIamTokenData())` which suggests that when running on Android, the app is unable to contact the server and get an IAM key. So it might be network / proxy / DNS related.

Comment: I guess that could be possible. But it is on the same wifi network. I also tested on my phone's data but no luck. I wouldn't know what to do to find out of it is something network related.